# Tabular model - Dinamic partitioning

Tags: ssas, tabular, partition

good morning, in a tabular model i've a fact table partitioned by the time dimension.
The first partition is the actual time (last 3 month) and the second parition is the previous period.

I scheduled only a full process for the actual parition 
<< DATEADD(month, -3 , getdate()) >> but when the month changes it obviously creates a data hole.

How I can avoid this? 
Is also required a full process monthly for previous partition?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create one partition for July 2019 and earlier, one for August 2019, one for September 2019 and one for October 2019. Process the most recent three partitions daily. Then once we hit November create a new November 2019 partition and only process the most recent three optionally you can merge the August 2019 partition with the July and earlier partition.

Answer (score 0):

Ok and how to create the novembre partition and set as the last one to be processed automatically  ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're partitioning facts by time, it's better to partition them by the same cadence (week, month, quarter, year, ...) to avoid this complexity altogether. The most used method is per year/month (201901, 201902, ...).
The best way to do this, is to keep them hardcoded, but generate them to avoid having to type all these partitions manually in your development tool, or the raw code of the .bim file.

Example for partition `201911`:

```
SELECT * FROM FactTable WHERE DateKey = 201911
```

This allows you to:

- Retain partitions as they're supposed to be (201901 will always have Jan 2019)
- Easily manage partitions by code (creating, processing scripts)
- Predict and prepare future empty partitions to avoid having to add partitions all the time. Preparing in advance doesn't cost you anything but a bit more text in the .bim file.

If you really want to roll with the 3 month rolling window, you can:

1. Process the 'actual' partition once the month switches
2. Make sure the older partitions have the same definition with multiples of 3 in `DATEADD`. The previous partition would be between 3 and 6 months ago, etc.

This is quite annoying to develop though, if you have a lot of partitions, or even a lot of facts with the same logic.

Keep in mind, the power of tabular partitions is that you do not have to re-process old data if it doesn't change. Processing all partitions with rolling logic beats the purpose of partitioning in tabular.